# Como descobrir a quanto tempo um aplicativo esta sendo executada?

Tags: windows, aplicação-desktop

Tenho que descobrir a quanto tempo um aplicativo no windows está sendo executado, o aplicativo em si, não foi eu quem criou o aplicativo, já pesquisei e não consegui encontrar nada, usando a logica, queria saber se tem como fazer de algumas das seguintes maneiras:

- Alguma propriedade do windows que indica isso;
- Fazer uma aplicação que fica escutando os processos em execução
  e grava o tempo;
- Algum tipo de "*Gambiarra*"?

Obrigado

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo posta como resposta que eu marco como resolvido, claro coloca uma breve explicação, etc... vlw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O programa Process Explorer que pode ser baixado [aqui](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) irá lhe demonstrar isso

Após executa-lo, pressione o botão direito do mouse sobre um processo e escolha "Properties" que ele irá lhe mostrar a hora em que o processo começou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]